# How to find integral of $\sin(x)x^2$

Tags: integration

It's possible the integral bellow. What way I must to use for solve it.

$$\int \sin(x)x^2dx$$

Comment: Apply parts twice

Comment: Hollywood to the rescue: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlN0We25DF4  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Try integration by parts twice.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Find the antiderivative of $\sin(ax)$, then differentiate it twice with regard to *a*, and let $a=1$.